# How to avoid job triggers when pushing inside job?

Tags: jenkins, github, jenkins-pipeline

I have Jenkins Pipeline job, which is using `Generic Webhook Trigger` with token. Inside of the pipeline script I have:

```
sh '''
    git add .
    git commit -m "Update..." || true
    git push origin main
'''
```

How can I prevent the job trigger from the push inside the the pipeline? At the moment I always have double triggers.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there are 2 options:

1. You disable the webhook
2. Use a when condition

I don't think you want to do the first one, so for the second one, there is the [when](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#when) condition.

```
// lines skipped for brevity
stage('myStage') {
  when {
    triggeredBy cause: 'UserIdCause'
  }

  steps {
    sh '''
      git add .
      git commit -m "Update..." || true
      git push origin main
    '''
  }
}
```

This will run only when a user presses the `Build` button. Though, if you would want to run the Job via a webhook event and still have the step that alters your repository (thus resulting in another change, another webhook event, and so on), probably you could commit with a certain message from the pipeline like `Jenkins automated commit`, then on the second webhook event, check the commit message (assuming this is possible, IDK) and don't run the step if it is the automated one.

I hope the first solution helps you since it's more elegant and easy to do. In my pipelines, I only let Jenkins push to my GitHub repo when I'm doing a release or something. Not on usual builds let's say.